# The type arguments for method cannot be inferred from the usage

Tags: types, unity-game-engine, arguments

This is my code and I'm trying to figure out what's the problem with this line..

instance = new GameObject( "gamestate").AddComponent ();

Here is the error that I'm getting: `The type arguments for method 'UnityEngine.GameObject.AddComponent<T>()' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly`

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class gamestate : MonoBehaviour
{

    //Declare Properties
    private static gamestate instance;

    public static gamestate Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if(instance == null)
            {
                instance = new GameObject( "gamestate").AddComponent ();
            }

            return instance;
        }
    }    

    public void startState()
    {
        print ("Creating a new game state");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
instance = new GameObject( "gamestate").AddComponent ();
```

Specifically, this call:

```
AddComponent ();
```

What sort of component do you want to add? Let's suppose you want to add an `AudioSource`:

```
AddComponent<AudioSource>();
```

From context, it looks like you want a `gamestate`:

```
AddComponent<gamestate>();
```

For your own reference, these are called [generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), which are similar to templates in C++.

As an aside, common practice is to capitalize class names (like `Gamestate` or `GameState`). The compiler won't care, but other developers might.

Answer (score 1):

I think I might be following the same example! ;-)

You should change the line:

```
instance = new GameObject( "gamestate").AddComponent ();
```

for:

```
instance = new GameObject( "gamestate").AddComponent<gamestate>();
```

Their full code is on this pastebin: http://pastebin.com/YPJTGLwX